# Text box focus not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to focus a text box programatically

Code:

```
<input></input>
<div id="click">Click</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#click").live("click",function()
{
    var inputbox=$(this).prev();
    $(inputbox).focus();
}
});
```

Here is the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/KwLF6/

Comment: Your `input` element has invalid (incomplete) markup and it's not a parent of any element.

Comment: it's a typo , edited the question

Comment: You have an extra `}` there. If you check your browser console, there's an error message: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`

Comment: Use `$(inputbox).focus();` instead of `$($(this).parent()).focus();`

Comment: And you also have missing this pair: `})`.

Comment: In other words, try to check for errors in the browser console, typos, missing/extra brackets, etc, before assuming your code doesn't work.

Comment: You do not need to wrap inputbox in $(); it is a jquery collection already.

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KwLF6/4/)**

Try this code,

1. **Important** - Include jQuery reference(In your fiddle as well as your actual code)
2. `.live()` is deprecated as of **jQuery 1.7**, so use **[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** instead.
3. Add appropriate closing paranthesis in each function. (Always try to check code errors through your browser console)

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#click").on("click",function(){
        $(this).prev().focus();
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning the `live` deprecation, and not creating an useless variable to receive the `input` element selection.

Answer (score 0):

try to use focusin() instead.
http://api.jquery.com/focusin/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#click").on("click",function()
   {
           var inputbox=$(this).prev();
           $(inputbox).focus();
   });
});
```

***[FIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/KwLF6/1/)***

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this version: http://jsfiddle.net/x9m5N/4/

Use

```
   inputbox.focus();
```

And input elements do need a type and do not need to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Frameworks & Extensions you did not select any JQuery Library

After Select JQuery1.8.3
 And modify the Js code like bellow its work for me

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#click").on("click",function()
   {
        var inputbox=$(this).prev();
        $(inputbox).focus(); 
   });
});
```

My idea is you have to check are you include Jquery library in your project or your Jquery library did not support focus() function